# scrollIntoView method does not work at all

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

actually, I searched the StackOverflow and I notice that there were many questions about the scrollIntoView method **smooth behavior** did not work in certain situations. but about me, it didn't work even in the simplest scenario, a site with minimum elements and styles. in fact, it does not work in my bigger project, but I just use it in a very simple code to see if it work there and it doesn't. I can't figure out what's the problem. I'll be appreciated if anyone tells me what's wrong with my code.
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis
      nesciunt quae, laboriosam cumque similique ex iusto ea ut! Laborum
      consequatur repudiandae ut deleniti, magnam veritatis. Temporibus quae
      unde at quasi.
    </div>
    <button>lorem</button>
    
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="jump-place">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia,
        labore voluptates earum atque dolores omnis nobis, eaque sapiente
        expedita iure nulla. Repellendus fugiat a iste impedit voluptates autem
        ex eius.
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src="temp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
.space {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: brown;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 100px;
}
.jump-place {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

my js:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.jump-place').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
})
```

Comment: Works absolutely fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/ptb31sz2/ (Tested in a current Chrome.)

Comment: Check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollintoview

Comment: @CBroe thanks CBroe, I did not make my point clear,  sorry about that, actually scrolling works fine, just the smooth part did not work! my problem is why it doesn't scroll smoothly

Comment: Scrolling _is_ smooth in the fiddle as well (if you view it with a browser that supports this option.)

Comment: @CBroe I can't see smooth scrolling! so maybe its my browser problem. thanks

Comment: IE and Safari do not support the options parameter yet, but apart from that, browser support should be good. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Options object for `scrollIntoView` not supported by Safari for now.
But you can use a polyfill https://github.com/magic-akari/seamless-scroll-polyfill